# C# Parsing Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a Game Called UnityCraft and I tried making a way to switch blocks!
Here is my Code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BuildScript : MonoBehaviour {

    RaycastHit hit;

    public int blockSelected = 1;

    public Transform prefab;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown(1)){
            blockSelected = 1;
        }

        if(Input.GetButtonDown(2)){
            blockSelected = 2;
        }

        if(blockSelected == 1){
            prefab = dirt;
        }

        if(blockSelected == 2){
            prefab = brick;
        }


        Ray ray = camera.ViewportPointToRay (new Vector3 (0.5f, 0.5f, 0));
        Vector3 G = new Vector3 (Mathf.Round (hit.point.x), Mathf.Ceil (hit.point.y), Mathf.Round (hit.point.z));

        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
                Destroy (hit.collider.gameObject);
                print ("Block Destroyed!");
            }

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1)) {
                Instantiate (prefab, G, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a prefab called brick and one called dirt, and they are linked to blocks.

Comment: It comes up with parsing error

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: In what line is the error? What is the error message?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the problem you're referring to is in the line

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown(1)){
```

That won't work, because [GetButtonDown](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html) does not have an integer argument. It takes a string, which you can find or define in the [input manager](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-InputManager.html).

From your code I do take it that you want to simply use number keys? In that case, don't use the `GetButton` calls, but use `GetKey` instead. So change your code to something like

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Keypad1)){
```

for the case where pressing <kbd>1</kbd> should trigger something.